# regexp all non-empty sequence of non-whitespace characters exept comma

Tags: regex, tcl

How to split line to the list using regexp(all  non-empty sequence of non-whitespace characters exept comma). I have try:

```
set list_  [regexp -inline -all {\S+\[,]} $line]
```

But it doesn't work.

So for example: 
for such lines:

```
NAME NAME2  X,Y X,Y X,Y X,Y
```

`X`, `Y` are floating-point numbers

result should be:

```
NAME NAME2  X Y X Y X Y X Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `regexp` and `-inline`, you can simply use:

```
% set list_ [regexp -inline -all -- {[^\s,]+} $line]
NAME NAME2  X Y X Y X Y X Y
```

`[^\s,]+` matches any non-space characters and non-commas.

Answer (score 1):

You could just change commas to spaces and then split on whitespace

```
set l [split [string map {, " "} $line]]
```

Or, use splitx from tcllib

```
package require textutil::split
set l [textutil::split::splitx $line {[,\s]+}]
```